# spring.config.additional-location as environmental variable

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker

I have a Docker image for a spring boot 2 app,
in the image I use spring.config.additional-location to pass a some properties stored in a file on the container itself.

Now I want to use this container in another as a layer in another container or use it in a docker-compose file and I may need to override the spring.config.additional-location.

I tried to override it in an ENV variable:
`SPRING_CONFIG_ADDITIONAL-LOCATION` with no success.

What is the proper way to achieve this.

Answer (score 9):

Value for spring.config.additional-location must be a directory path and not a file path. I'm not sure if this is a bug or a feature, since spring.config.location allows both.

For example inside docker-compose.yml you can set spring.config.additional-location as:

```
version: '3'
    services:
      myapp:
        build: .
        environment:      
          - "SPRING_CONFIG_ADDITIONAL-LOCATION=file:/opt/myapp/config/"
          - "SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=production"
...
```

Then Spring Boot will look up for /opt/myapp/config/application-production.properties file to load properties from.

More about this in [Spring Boot Externalized Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)

Comment: Probably you are using an old version, but `SPRING_CONFIG_ADDITIONAL-LOCATION` does not exist, at least in Spring boot 2.6. The correct env variable name is `SPRING_CONFIG_ADDITIONAL_LOCATION`